# scraped data using BeautifulSoup does not match source code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mismatch

I'm new to webscraping. I have seen a few tutorials on how to scrape websites using beautifulsoup.
As an exercise I would like to extract data from a real estate website.
The specific page I want to scrape is this one: https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/maison-et-appartement/a-vendre?countries=BE&page=1

My goal is to extract a list of all the links to each real estate sale.
Afterwards, I want to loop through that list of links to extract all the data for each sale (price, location, nb bedrooms etc.)

The first issue I'm encountering is that the data scraped using the classic beautifulsoup code did not match the source code of the webpage.

This is my code:

```
URL = "https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/maison-et-appartement/a-vendre?countries=BE&page=1"
page = requests.get(URL)
html = page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Hence, when looking for the links of each real estate sale which is located under

```
soup.find_all("a", class_="card__title-link")
```

It outputs an empty list. Indeed these  tags were actually not properly extracted from my code above.
Why is that? What should I do to ensure that the extracted html correctly corresponds to what is visible in the source code of the website?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

The data you see is embedded within the page in Json format. You can use this example how to load it:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/maison-et-appartement/a-vendre?countries=BE&page=1"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.find("iw-search")[":results"])

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print some data:
for ad in data:
    print(
        "{:<63} {:<8} {}".format(
            ad["property"]["title"],
            ad["transaction"]["sale"]["price"] or "-",
            "https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/{}".format(ad["id"]),
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
Triplex appartement met 3 slaapkamers en garage.                239000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9309298
Appartement                                                     285000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9309895
Heel ruime, moderne, lichtrijke Duplex te koop, bij centrum     269000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9303797
À VENDRE PAR LANDBERGH : appartement de deux chambres à Gand    359000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9310300
Prachtige nieuwbouw appartementen                               -        https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9309278
Prachtige nieuwbouw appartementen                               -        https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9309251
Prachtige nieuwbouw appartementen                               -        https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9309264
Appartement intéressant avec agréable vue panoramique verdoy    219000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9309366
Projet Utopia by Godin                                          -        https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9309458
Appartement 2-ch avec vue unique!                               270000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9309183
Residentieel wonen in Hélécine, dichtbij de natuur en de sne    -        https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9309241
Appartement                                                     375000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9309187
DUPLEX LUMIEUX ET SPACIEUX                                      380000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9298271
SINT-PIETERS-LEEUW / Magnifique maison de ±130m² avec jardin    430000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9310259
PARC PARMENTIER // APP MODERNE 3CH                              490000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9262193
BOIS DE LA CAMBRE – AV DE FRE – CLINIQUES DE L’EUROPE           575000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9309664
Entre Stockel et le Stade Fallon                                675000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9310094
Maisons neuves dans un cadre verdoyant                          -        https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/6792221
Nieuwbouwproject Dockside Gardens - Gent                        -        https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9008956
Appartement                                                     139000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9187904
A VENDRE CHEZ LANDBERGH: appartements à Merelbeke Flora         -        https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9306877
Très beau studio avec une belle vue sur la plage et la mer!     319000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9306787
BEL APPARTEMENT LUMINEUX DIAMANT / PLASKY                       320000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9264748
Un projet d'appartements neufs à proximité de Woluwé-St-Lamb    -        https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9308037
PLACE JOURDAN - 2 CHAMBRES                                      345000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9306953
Magnifiek appartement in de Brugse Rand - Assebroek             399000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9306613
Bien d'exception                                                415000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9308022
Appartement                                                     435000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9307802
Magnifique maison 5CH - 3SDB - bureau - dressing - garage       465000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9307178
Magnifique maison 5CH - 3SDB - bureau - dressing - garage       465000   https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9307177
```

---

EDIT: Added URL column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick response! However, I'm still confused by the fact that the data extracted still doesn't exactly match the code as shown in the source code. When I "inspect" the elements of the webpage, I can see the code for each house to be sold. Including the hyperlink tag: `<a id href="https://....." aria-label="Triplex a vendre..." class="card-title__link">` I'm actually intrested in this hyperlink, and I would like to extract all of them.

Comment: Also, how can I spot when the format is Json?

Comment: @LBedo I've updated the answer. The URL is constructed dynamically via Javascript. But when you open the link, eg. `https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9307177` you will be redirected to the correct listing.

Comment: @AnrejKesely, I'm getting back to this code today to extract this data again. You helped me a lot last time with your piece of code. Unfortunately, I don't understand why it leads me to an error now. At `data = json.loads(soup.find("iw-search")[":results"])` it gets me the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable". Yet, each time I run it, it loops through my list of urls, but then after a random number of iterations it then yeilds this error. I hope you can help me again. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @LBedo What kind of error do you get? Isn't it captcha page? If it is, probably you need to limit your crawling speed.

Comment: `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-747c19d8bdc7> in <module>
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
---> data = json.loads(soup.find("iw-search")[":results"])
     
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @LBedo Put the code inside `try...except` block and upon exception `print(soup)`. Observe, if the data are there.

Comment: So, I'm not sure why it didn't bug this time. I added the ´try... except: print(soup)´ as you suggested, and it has looped throughout without bug, it didn't use the except clause. So, thank you again !